# Debezium Postgres Kafka not creating topic

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I am new to kafka and am using debezium kafka to track changes in my postgrest table. Following is my docker-complse.yml

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "hadoop-distributed-file-system"
    driver: local
    
services: 
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: debezium/postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mosip123
      - POSTGRES_DB=anonprofile
    # to activate WAL 
    # command: postgres -c wal_level=logical -c archive_mode=on -c max_wal_senders=5
    
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
      - ./PostgresDB:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
  
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    container_name: zookeeper
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace

  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=LISTENER_EXT://localhost:29092,LISTENER_INT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=LISTENER_INT:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_EXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=LISTENER_INT://0.0.0.0:9092,LISTENER_EXT://0.0.0.0:29092
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=LISTENER_INT
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace    
  
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

The shell script inside postgres container.
Please note the datatype is JSON, if that is the source of the error?

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-13-pgoutput
psql -U postgres -d anonprofile <<-EOSQL
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anon_profiles (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, profiledata JSON );
    ALTER TABLE anon_profiles REPLICA IDENTITY USING INDEX anon_profiles_pkey;
    ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level to 'logical';
EOSQL
```

The connector json file

```
{ "name": "anonprofile-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "user",
    "database.password": "mosip123",
    "database.dbname" : "anonprofile",
    "database.server.name": "MOSIP",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.anon_profiles",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "publication.autocreate.mode": "all_tables",
    "publication.name": "my_publication",
    "snapshot.mode": "always"
  }
}
```

After setting everything up I don't find any errors but by examining the topics list, no topic is being created for the above postgres connection. Am I missing something?

Topics list

```
$docker exec -it \
  $(docker ps | grep kafka | awk '{ print $1 }') \
  /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
__consumer_offsets
my_connect_configs
my_connect_offsets
my_connect_statuses
```

Comment: Where did you search for errors? Do you have auto topic creation disabled? What happens when you create the topic before starting Debezium - does it actually run?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't manually disable auto topic creation. How do I enable it though, in case it's disabled? No, creating the topic manually doesn't run. It shows in the list but it doesn't accept the message (I mean I am not able to see the DB changes in it).

Comment: I'm new to kafka, and according to the material available online, I was expecting the topic to be created automatically.

Comment: Refer- https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thankyou so much, I have resolved the issue. What I was doing was while creating the postgres container, I was already creating the table through an entrypoint shell script (before I ran the CURL command to connect kafka and postgres) thus the topic wasn't being created.

Comment: AFAIK, the Postgres scripts don't control Kafka topic creation. If the broker has auto topic creation enabled, it'll get created upon the first producer request. Otherwise, Connect API itself has its own topic creation settings, as mentioned in that page

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm facing the same issue again, and now the database isn't in my control. I went through the documentation you shared. I added the ```CONNECT_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE=true``` for the connect container, but it made no difference. Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Exec into the Connect container and find the connect-distributed properties file and make sure that value is set correctly

Comment: @OneCricketeer ```topic.creation.enable=true``` is set in the file.

Comment: That's good news, I guess... I've never really used Debezium, so unfortunately other than those docs, I'm not sure where the issue would be

Comment: @OneCricketeer found it, not taking credit cause a friend helped me, but putting it here in case someone faces the issue. The database.user should be a superuser (postgres). Earlier with my other user, it didn't have permission to create replication slots.

Comment: Please put your solution below as an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `database.user`, the user needs to have access to create replication slots. Setting it as `postgres` did the work. Or else grant the user with the required permissions (I guess that would be to make it as a superuser).